# C# How to adding each element from an array to sub-Node in XML tree?

Tags: c#, arrays, xml

I want insert each element from an array add them to a XML tree.

```
List<String> list = {"abc","cba","bca"};  
NameList.Add(new XElement("movie", new XElement("title", this.textBox1.Text), new XElement("genre",list)));
```

This statement just create stuff like this:

```
<movie>
<title>smoething</title>
<genre>abccbabca</genre>
</movie>
```

I want create like this:

```
<movie>
<title>smoething</title>
<genre>abc</genre>
<genre>cba</genre>
<genre>bca</genre>
</movie>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a very simple solution using LINQ:

```
List<String> list = {"abc","cba","bca"}; 
NameList.Add(new XElement("movie", new XElement("title", this.textBox1.Text), list.Select(l => new XElement("genre", l))));
```

Comment: Cool! It is just awesome!

Answer (score 2):

using for loop could be a way

```
        var strList = new List<string> {"abc", "cba", "bca"};
        var xml = new XmlDocument();
        var root = xml.AppendChild(xml.CreateElement("Movie"));
        root.AppendChild(xml.CreateElement("Title")).InnerText = "somthing";

        foreach (var str in strList)
        {
            root.AppendChild(xml.CreateElement("Genre")).InnerText = str;
        }

        MessageBox.Show(xml.OuterXml);
```